# Dragging a sum index formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got a formula working in my spreadsheet, which is:

=SUM(INDEX($D$13:$HA$25,,1))

This is summing the number of hours in column 1,  rows 13-25 perfectly and if I manually change the 1, it will look at column 2.  However, I need to drag that formula downwards so that the column number goes up by 1 automatically, as I have hundreds of columns I need to apply the formula to. Any idea how to do this?

(also can we take a moment to curse the person who set up one part of the spreadsheet horizontally, and the other part vertically?  I can't change t because the client has said they like the current format!!)

I'm in Office 365 ProPlus.

Thankyou

Comment: change the `1` to `ROW(1:1)` and it will do it.

Comment: So simple! But has worked perfectly. Thankyou very much indeed.